# MySQL alternate for db2 final table

Tags: mysql, db2

In DB2

```
SELECT id FROM FINAL TABLE (
INSERT INTO mytable (x,y,z) VALUES (1,2,3)
)
```

Works to give me back ANY data from the table / row inserted.

Is there an equivalent for this in MySQL?  I'd like to avoid a transaction and two queries to do something that is possible in one.

Comment: Not possible to do in one query with MySQL.

Comment: Are you just trying to do `last_insert_id()`? That doesn't require a transaction.

Comment: @barmar... kinda - but I want more than just the id.

Comment: Mysql doesn't have that functionality, sorry. P.S. Don't put "..." after @name, it prevents SO from recognizing it and sending notifications.

Comment: thx for the heads up on the ellipse